# health monitoring in mvc3

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to do a health monitoring in mvc3 application.

I am doing with eventviewer. But I want to save these events and errors to store into Sql server database.

```
<healthMonitoring enabled="true"  heartbeatInterval="10">
       <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="EventLogProvider" type="System.Web.Management.EventLogWebEventProvider,System.Web,Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />

    <add connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" maxEventDetailsLength="1073741823"
        buffer="false" bufferMode="Notification" name="SqlWebEventProviderlane"
        type="System.Web.Management.SqlWebEventProvider,System.Web,Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />

  </providers>

  <profiles>
    <add name="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:01:00"
                custom="" />
            <add name="Critical" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:00"
                custom="" />
  </profiles>

  <rules>
    <clear/>

    <add name="All Errors Default" eventName="All Events" provider="EventLogProvider"
        profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:01:00"
        custom="" />
    <add name="Failure Audits Default" eventName="Failure Audits"
        provider="EventLogProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1"
        maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:01:00" custom="" />
  </rules>

  <eventMappings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="All Events" type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseEvent,System.Web,Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
          startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647" />
          <add name="All Errors" type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent,System.Web,Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
        startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647" />
         </eventMappings>

</healthMonitoring>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the rules section, you have to refer to the provider with the name 'SqlWebEventProviderlane':

```
<add name="All Errors Default" eventName="All Events" provider="SqlWebEventProviderlane" 
    profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:01:00" 
    custom="" />
```

Then you have to provide a connection string with the name 'LocalSqlServer' in the  section, which points to your database.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=serverName;initial catalog=yourDataBase;..."/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And you have to prepare your database with the tool aspnet_regsql.